# What is wrong with my config? SEVERE: IOException while loading persisted sessions: java.io.EOFException

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a web program using struts2, spring3 and hibernate 4 running in Tomcat. It can work, but Tomcat reports a `java.io.EOFException`.

The following is the tomcat log:

```
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.29\webapps\manager
九月 10, 2012 4:27:02 下午 org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager doLoad
SEVERE: IOException while loading persisted sessions: java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2298)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2767)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:298)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(CustomObjectInputStream.java:58)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:204)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.startInternal(StandardManager.java:491)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5294)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1100)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1618)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

九月 10, 2012 4:27:02 下午 org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager startInternal
SEVERE: Exception loading sessions from persistent storage
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2298)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2767)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:298)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(CustomObjectInputStream.java:58)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:204)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.startInternal(StandardManager.java:491)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5294)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1100)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1618)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: If you are using eclipse you can right click on your server and select "Clean Tomcat Work Directory" also.

Answer (score 56):

You can delete `${catalina.home}/work/Catalina/localhost/<app>/SESSION.ser` where app is your application.

Comment: I'd been cleaning my working directory to no effect. After reading this I physically removed, cleaned, added back in and then cleaned again. That worked... thanks!

Comment: I had to delete the whole work/ directory to solve the problem.

Answer (score 7):

You can delete ${CATALINA_HOME}/work/Catalina/localhost/test

where test is your application folder (war name).

This solved my issue

Answer (score 3):

Try deleting tomcat's Work folder, then restart tomcat. It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I am having a project in eclipse and using tomcat plugin to run it, I tried this but it didn't help, so I observed in my project directory structure there is one more work directory, I removed that directory and everything started working. Just wanted to share this one more possible answer for others like me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the methods above : "delete work directory" in the ${CATALINA_HOME}/work/Catalina/localhost, "uncomment manager pathname" in the ${CATALINA_HOME}/conf/context.xml. Not worked.

And I found that in my eclipse projects, the server project had a file called "context.xml" too, it must be copied when the server project was created.  And I "uncomment manager pathname" there, it worked finally!

Hope it will help someone!

Answer (score 0):

As @GauravS said. I am using eclipse so when I right click on tomcat Server (in Servers window) and clean it it worked...

Sometimes I have to remove the war from tomcat, clean than run it again.

Sometimes I delete tomcat and right click on Servers window, New , Server and I use same ports I was using and delete the old server.

PS: to open Servers window:

```
Window - Show View - Other - write "Servers" and choose it from the list - OK
```